# how to resolve http 400 error?

Tags: jquery, spring

i have table with each row contains a delete link and add link is there at below table,,,the problem is after adding some 3 rows by clicking in add link and then if delete rows from bottom by clicking on delete link at each row...the delete link not working for the second time deletion from the bottom.....like if you delete last row and again if you delete once again the latest last row then its showing 400 error,,,,can any one hepl me?
my function for deleting rows in my table as below:

```
$('#remNew1')
.live(
    'click',
function() {

    var targetId = $('#newfileid').val();
var fileName = $("#" + targetId).val();
var cnt = parseInt($("#noOfFiles").val());
    var agree = confirm("Are you sure? If you choose OK, 
    This Template will be Removed");
if (agree) {
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
  $('#listfiles tr').each(function (i) {
        var index = i + 1;
      $('td:first .file_name', this).text('File ' + index + ':');
   })

somethingChanged = true;
    cnt = cnt - 1;
$("#noOfFiles").attr("value", cnt);
if (fileName == undefined) {
window.location = "files_formulae.htm?projectId="
            + $;
    {
        project.projectId;
    };
    } 
} else
    return false;
});


});
```

and my table looks like:

```
<table>
<td><input type="text" name="name" value="aaa"/></td>
<a id="remNew1" href="#"  class='delete-file'>Delete file</a>
</td>
</table>
<a href="#" id="addNew" class='add-file'>Add additional file</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to incorrect syntax:

```
{
      project.projectId;
}
```

The correct one is:

```
( 
    project.projectId;
)
```